# First Difference Bootstrap from Negative Binomial

Tags: r, glm, statistics-bootstrap

novice here. I am fitting a negative binomial model on count data where Y is the count of events, D is the treatment, and X is a logarithmic offset:

```
out <- glm.nb(y ~ d + offset(log(x)),data=d1)
```

I would like to bootstrap the confidence intervals of the first difference between D=1 and D=0. I've gotten this far, but not sure if it is the correct approach:

```
holder <- matrix(NA,1200,1)
out <- out <- glm.nb(y ~ d + offset(log(x)),data=d1)

for (i in 1:1200){
q <- sample(1:nrow(d1), 1)
d2 <- d1[q,]
d1_1 <- d1_2 <- d2
d1_1$d <- 1
d1_2$d <- 0
d1pred <- predict(out,d1_1,type="response")
d2pred <- predict(out,d1_2,type="response")
holder[i,1] <- (d1pred[1] - d2pred[1])
}
mean(holder)
```

Is this the correct way to bootstrap the first difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, your approach is ok, but you can do it in more *R-ish* way. Firstly, if you are serious about bootstrapping you can employ `boot` library and benefit from more compact code, no loops and many other advanced options.

In your case it can look like:

```
## Data generation
N <- 100
set.seed(1)
d1 <- data.frame(y=rbinom(N, N, 0.5),
                 d=rbinom(N, 1, 0.5),
                 x=rnorm(N, 10, 3))
## Model
out <- glm.nb(y ~ d + offset(log(x)), data=d1)

## Statistic function (what we are bootstrapping)
## Returns difference between D=1 and D=0
diff <- function(x,i,model){
  v1 <- v2 <- x[i,]
  v1$d <- 1
  v2$d <- 0
  predict(model,v1,type="response") - predict(model,v2,type="response")
}

## Bootstrapping itself
b <- boot(d1, diff, R=5e3, model=out)
mean(b$t)
```

Now `b$t` holds bootstrapped values. See `names(b)` and/or `?boot` for extra information.

Bootstrapping is time consuming operation, and one of the obvious advantage of `boot` library is support for parallel operations. It's as easy as:

```
 b <- boot(d1, diff, R=5e3, model=out, parallel="multicore", ncpus=2)
```

If you are on Windows use `parallel="snow"` instead.